# Display Content from Array to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display my AboutPageContent.js to AboutPage.js. I would assume I would have to map it out somehow, but I'm not sure how.

#### Relevant Code

**AboutPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';

// CSS import statements
import '../css/AboutPage.css';
import '../css/App.css';

// Content import Statements
import AboutPageContent from '../content/AboutPageContent.js';

class About extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = AboutPageContent;
    }

    render() {
    return(
        <div className='about-page'>
            <div className='page-header'>{this.state.about.name}</div>
            <div>{this.state.about.desc.map(paragraph => <p>{paragraph}</p>)}</div>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default About;
```

**AboutPageContent.js**

```
let AboutPageContent = {
    about: [{
        name: 'About Me',
        desc: [
            'p1',
            'p2',
            'p3',
            'p4',
            'p5',
            'p6'
        ],
        id: 1
}]};

export default AboutPageContent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do 2 `map`s, 1 for `state.about` and another one for `state.about[i].desc`.

```js
class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = AboutPageContent;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="about-page">
        <div className="page-header">{this.state.about.name}</div>
        <div>
          {this.state.about.map((currAbout) =>
            currAbout.desc.map((paragraph, i) => <p key={i}>{paragraph}</p>)
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or if you want to display the current `about.name`, move the `<div className='page-header'>...` inside `this.state.about` loop.

```js
class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = AboutPageContent;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="about-page">
        <div>
          {this.state.about.map((currAbout, i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
              <div className="page-header">{currAbout.name}</div>
              {currAbout.desc.map((paragraph, i) => (
                <p key={i}>{paragraph}</p>
              ))}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit magical-minsky-iv50i]

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.state.about` is an array, so you can't reference the `name` and `desc` properties with dot notation. Currently, `this.state.about.name` would be undefined. `this.state.about[0].name` would be equal to 'About Me'.

I would simply remove the [ ]s around the `this.state.about` property. That would make it an object (as opposed to an array) so the rest of your code should work fine. Leave `this.state.about.desc` as an array so you can use the map method.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object in about this way `state.about[0]`

```js
const AboutPageContent = {
  about: [
    {
      name: "About Me",
      desc: ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6"],
      id: 1,
    },
  ],
};


class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = AboutPageContent;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="about-page">
        <div className="page-header">{this.state.about[0].name}</div>
        <div>
          {this.state.about[0].desc.map((paragraph) => (
            <p>{paragraph}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <About />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

However if you have more than one property in the object and you want to display description by name you could try this

```js
const AboutPageContent = {
  about: [
    {
      name: "About Me",
      desc: ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6"],
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      name: " Section 2",
      desc: ["p12", "p10"],
      id: 1,
    },
  ],
};


class About extends React.Component {
   state = AboutPageContent;
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="about-page">
      <div className="page-header">
         {Object.values(this.state)
            .flat()
            .map((o, i) => (
              <React.Fragment key={i}>
                <p>{o.name}</p>
                {o.desc.map((paragraph) => (
                  <p>{paragraph}</p>
                ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <About />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

 <div id="root"></div>
```